# Averaging two entries if two entries entered

Tags: sql, t-sql, report

Hello Stackoverflow members,

I'm having trouble in understanding how to complete a SQL query. Currently we have two 'checkouts' that complete transactions, we then monitor the productivity of each one. However, recently we've created an average checkout productivity (hourly)

The issue is the average is merely adding both entries up and not creating an average.

The SQL code should do as follows:

```
Checkout 1 : 25 transactions 
Checkout 2 : 50 transactions
```

Work out the average between them both (hourly) = /60
I thought I could merely write divide by 2 however, obviously if only one checkout was working this would divide the 1 checkout by 2.
Therefore should complete the following: 
IF: Only one transaction don't DIVIDE!

```
Checkout 1: 25 transactions
checkout 2: 0 transactions
```

Currently we have some SQL code that adds then together but doesn't do anything else with the data.

I understand a case statement would allow me to do this?

EDIT----

```
((SELECT SUM(total_moves) from Checkouts.db.checkout.transaction_statistics 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout_details ON checkout.transaction_statistics.vvd_gkey = checkout_details.vvd_gkey
INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.xps_che ON checkout_statistics.checkout_gkey = Checkouts.db.xps_che.gkey 
                WHERE flex_string01 = Transaction_id and short_name IN ('2.1', '2.2')) / 

                case when
                 (convert(decimal(12,2),(
((SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,

( SELECT CASE WHEN
(SELECT MIN(Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.t_carry_complete) 
        FROM   Checkouts.db.inv_move_event 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout_details ON Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.to_pos_locid = flex_string01 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout.transaction_statistics ON checkout_details.vvd_gkey = checkout.transaction_statistics.vvd_gkey
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.xps_che ON checkout_statistics.checkout_gkey = Checkouts.db.xps_che.gkey 
        WHERE  to_pos_locid = Transaction_id
            AND move_kind != 'Floor'    
            and short_name IN ('2.1', '2.2')
            ) <
            (   SELECT MIN(Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.t_carry_complete)
        FROM   Checkouts.db.inv_move_event 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout_details ON Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.fm_pos_locid = flex_string01
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout.transaction_statistics ON checkout_details.vvd_gkey = checkout.transaction_statistics.vvd_gkey
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.xps_che ON checkout_statistics.checkout_gkey = Checkouts.db.xps_che.gkey 
            WHERE  fm_pos_locid = Transaction_id
            AND move_kind != 'Floor'and short_name IN ('2.1', '2.2'))
        THEN (SELECT MIN(Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.t_carry_complete)
        FROM   Checkouts.db.inv_move_event 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout_details ON Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.to_pos_locid = flex_string01
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout.transaction_statistics ON checkout_details.vvd_gkey = checkout.transaction_statistics.vvd_gkey
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.xps_che ON checkout_statistics.checkout_gkey = Checkouts.db.xps_che.gkey 
        WHERE  to_pos_locid = Transaction_id
            AND move_kind != 'Floor'and short_name IN ('2.1', '2.2')
            ) ELSE
(   SELECT MIN(Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.t_carry_complete) 
        FROM   Checkouts.db.inv_move_event 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout_details ON Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.fm_pos_locid = flex_string01
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout.transaction_statistics ON checkout_details.vvd_gkey = checkout.transaction_statistics.vvd_gkey
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.xps_che ON checkout_statistics.checkout_gkey = Checkouts.db.xps_che.gkey 
            WHERE  fm_pos_locid = Transaction_id
            AND move_kind != 'Floor' and short_name IN ('2.1', '2.2'))
            END)
,
( SELECT CASE WHEN
(SELECT MAX(Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.t_carry_complete) 
        FROM   Checkouts.db.inv_move_event 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout_details ON Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.to_pos_locid = flex_string01 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout.transaction_statistics ON checkout_details.vvd_gkey = checkout.transaction_statistics.vvd_gkey
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.xps_che ON checkout_statistics.checkout_gkey = Checkouts.db.xps_che.gkey 
        WHERE  to_pos_locid = Transaction_id
            AND move_kind != 'Floor'    
            and short_name IN ('2.1', '2.2')
            ) >
            (   SELECT MAX(Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.t_carry_complete)
        FROM   Checkouts.db.inv_move_event 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout_details ON Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.fm_pos_locid = flex_string01
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout.transaction_statistics ON checkout_details.vvd_gkey = checkout.transaction_statistics.vvd_gkey
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.xps_che ON checkout_statistics.checkout_gkey = Checkouts.db.xps_che.gkey 
            WHERE  fm_pos_locid = Transaction_id
            AND move_kind != 'Floor'and short_name IN ('2.1', '2.2'))
        THEN (SELECT MAX(Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.t_carry_complete)
        FROM   Checkouts.db.inv_move_event 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout_details ON Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.to_pos_locid = flex_string01
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout.transaction_statistics ON checkout_details.vvd_gkey = checkout.transaction_statistics.vvd_gkey
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.xps_che ON checkout_statistics.checkout_gkey = Checkouts.db.xps_che.gkey 
        WHERE  to_pos_locid = Transaction_id
            AND move_kind != 'Floor'and short_name IN ('2.1', '2.2')
            ) ELSE
(   SELECT MAX(Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.t_carry_complete) 
        FROM   Checkouts.db.inv_move_event 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout_details ON Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.fm_pos_locid = flex_string01
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout.transaction_statistics ON checkout_details.vvd_gkey = checkout.transaction_statistics.vvd_gkey
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.xps_che ON checkout_statistics.checkout_gkey = Checkouts.db.xps_che.gkey 
            WHERE  fm_pos_locid = Transaction_id
            AND move_kind != 'Floor' and short_name IN ('2.1', '2.2'))
            END)

) ) / 60 )))) = '0' THEN null else

(convert(decimal(12,2),(
((SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,

( SELECT CASE WHEN
(SELECT MIN(Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.t_carry_complete) 
        FROM   Checkouts.db.inv_move_event 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout_details ON Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.to_pos_locid = flex_string01 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout.transaction_statistics ON checkout_details.vvd_gkey = checkout.transaction_statistics.vvd_gkey
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.xps_che ON checkout_statistics.checkout_gkey = Checkouts.db.xps_che.gkey 
        WHERE  to_pos_locid = Transaction_id
            AND move_kind != 'Floor'    
            and short_name IN ('2.1', '2.2')
            ) <
            (   SELECT MIN(Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.t_carry_complete)
        FROM   Checkouts.db.inv_move_event 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout_details ON Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.fm_pos_locid = flex_string01
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout.transaction_statistics ON checkout_details.vvd_gkey = checkout.transaction_statistics.vvd_gkey
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.xps_che ON checkout_statistics.checkout_gkey = Checkouts.db.xps_che.gkey 
            WHERE  fm_pos_locid = Transaction_id
            AND move_kind != 'Floor'and short_name IN ('2.1', '2.2'))
        THEN (SELECT MIN(Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.t_carry_complete)
        FROM   Checkouts.db.inv_move_event 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout_details ON Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.to_pos_locid = flex_string01
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout.transaction_statistics ON checkout_details.vvd_gkey = checkout.transaction_statistics.vvd_gkey
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.xps_che ON checkout_statistics.checkout_gkey = Checkouts.db.xps_che.gkey 
        WHERE  to_pos_locid = Transaction_id
            AND move_kind != 'Floor'and short_name IN ('2.1', '2.2')
            ) ELSE
(   SELECT MIN(Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.t_carry_complete) 
        FROM   Checkouts.db.inv_move_event 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout_details ON Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.fm_pos_locid = flex_string01
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout.transaction_statistics ON checkout_details.vvd_gkey = checkout.transaction_statistics.vvd_gkey
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.xps_che ON checkout_statistics.checkout_gkey = Checkouts.db.xps_che.gkey 
            WHERE  fm_pos_locid = Transaction_id
            AND move_kind != 'Floor' and short_name IN ('2.1', '2.2'))
            END)
,
( SELECT CASE WHEN
(SELECT MAX(Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.t_carry_complete) 
        FROM   Checkouts.db.inv_move_event 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout_details ON Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.to_pos_locid = flex_string01 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout.transaction_statistics ON checkout_details.vvd_gkey = checkout.transaction_statistics.vvd_gkey
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.xps_che ON checkout_statistics.checkout_gkey = Checkouts.db.xps_che.gkey 
        WHERE  to_pos_locid = Transaction_id
            AND move_kind != 'Floor'    
            and short_name IN ('2.1', '2.2')
            ) >
            (   SELECT MAX(Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.t_carry_complete)
        FROM   Checkouts.db.inv_move_event 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout_details ON Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.fm_pos_locid = flex_string01
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout.transaction_statistics ON checkout_details.vvd_gkey = checkout.transaction_statistics.vvd_gkey
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.xps_che ON checkout_statistics.checkout_gkey = Checkouts.db.xps_che.gkey 
            WHERE  fm_pos_locid = Transaction_id
            AND move_kind != 'Floor'and short_name IN ('2.1', '2.2'))
        THEN (SELECT MAX(Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.t_carry_complete)
        FROM   Checkouts.db.inv_move_event 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout_details ON Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.to_pos_locid = flex_string01
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout.transaction_statistics ON checkout_details.vvd_gkey = checkout.transaction_statistics.vvd_gkey
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.xps_che ON checkout_statistics.checkout_gkey = Checkouts.db.xps_che.gkey 
        WHERE  to_pos_locid = Transaction_id
            AND move_kind != 'Floor'and short_name IN ('2.1', '2.2')
            ) ELSE
(   SELECT MAX(Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.t_carry_complete) 
        FROM   Checkouts.db.inv_move_event 
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout_details ON Checkouts.db.inv_move_event.fm_pos_locid = flex_string01
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.checkout.transaction_statistics ON checkout_details.vvd_gkey = checkout.transaction_statistics.vvd_gkey
        INNER JOIN Checkouts.db.xps_che ON checkout_statistics.checkout_gkey = Checkouts.db.xps_che.gkey 
            WHERE  fm_pos_locid = Transaction_id
            AND move_kind != 'Floor' and short_name IN ('2.1', '2.2'))
            END)

) ) / 60 ))))END

) AS [Average Checkout Productivity],
```

Kind Regards,
Ryan

Comment: You should post some SQL. It's hard to understand what you're trying to do based on your description alone.

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't divide 25+0 by 2. It is an avarage of 12.5. Whether this is so, because checkout 2 was not available or simply not being used, we don't know. Same for 25+1 in my opinion; we don't know whether checkout 2 was available only part time or simply seldomly used.

Comment: @JC. please see attached

Answer (score 0):

Case statement can work to check if the checkouts have fired.

so try something like this :

```
Select 
 case when Checkout1 <> 0 and Checkout2 <> 0 then divide  else dosomthing 
from yourtable
```

Assuming the checkout results are in  a table